# Extending Laravel's Validator Class

Tags: laravel, validation, extend

I am using the Laravel's validator class, and when validation fails I print out the errors with this method:

```
$validator->messages();
```

The method returns a multi dimensional array, I need a single dimensional array.

```
$validator->net_method();
```

How will I go about extending a new method to return the errors in a different format?

Comment: what's your need? it is a multi dimensional array for a reason.

Comment: I'm using angularJS for the front end, and simply want to just loop through a single dimensional array, I guess I can just write an filter to handle it.

Comment: can you give an example of the array so that i can work on?

Comment: Laravel's way:
array( 'title' => array('error msg 1', 'error msg 2'), 'description' => array('error msg 1'));

My way:
array('error 1', 'error 2', 'error 3');